# NLMS Algorithm is not converging, multiple implementation resulting equally

Tags: algorithm, matlab, signal-processing

The Normalized Least Mean Square algorithm is used in digital filtering, it basically tries to imitate an "unknown" filter so their difference (which is considered the error) tends to zero. The "factor" of convergence is that the error will start very high and with the continuous run of the algorithm it will be smaller.

The only difference between NLMS and LMS (which is its successor) is that NLMS normalizes the entry of the filter, so it won't be ease to high input power.

There are equations for both of the algorithms in the wiki page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_mean_squares_filter that is similar to my implementation of it.

I'm currently using an adaptative plant so I can filter a white noise input into a lowpass filter and try to adapt my algorithm coefficients to immitate the lowpass, its implemented in matlab:

```
clear all;close all;clc;

fid = fopen('ruidoBranco.pcm', 'rb');
s = fread(fid, 'int16');
fclose(fid);

itera = length(s);
L = 50;
passo = 0.00000000001;
H = passaBaixa(L,1000,2);
W = zeros(L,1);
y = zeros(itera,1);
sav_erro = zeros(itera,1);

for i=(L+1):itera,
    D=0;
    Y=0;
    for j=1:(L),
        Y = Y + W(j,1)*s(i-j,1);
        D = D + H(j,1)*s(i-j,1);
    end
    erro = D-Y;
    k=passo*erro;
    for j=1:(L),
        W(j,1) = W(j,1)+(k*s(i-j,1)/(s(i-j,1)^2+0.000001));
    end
    sav_erro(i,1) = (erro);
end
subplot(2,1,1);
plot(sav_erro);
subplot(2,1,2);
plot(W);
hold on;
plot(H,'r');

fid = fopen('saidaFIR.pcm', 'wb');
fwrite(fid,sav_erro,'int16');
fclose(fid);
```

The "passaBaixa" function is the lowpass filter that I was saying before:

```
function H = passaBaixa(M,FC,op)
    iteracoes = M;
    FS=8000;
    FC=FC/FS;
    M=iteracoes;
    H = zeros(iteracoes,1);
    for i=1:iteracoes,                                          
        if(i-M/2==0)
           H(i,1)=2*pi*FC;
        else
            H(i,1)=sin(2*pi*FC*(i-M/2))/(i-M/2);
        end
        if(op==1)
            H(i,1)=H(i,1);
        else if (op==2)
                 H(i,1) = H(i,1)*(0.42-0.5*cos(2*pi*i/M)+0.08*cos(4*pi*i/M));
            else
                 H(i,1)=H(i,1)*(0.54-0.46*cos(2*pi*i/M));
            end
        end
    end
    soma = sum(H);
    for i=1:iteracoes,
        H(i,1)=H(i,1)/soma;
    end
end
```

The file ruidoBranco.pcm is simply an white noise generated with 80.000 samples.

The obtained result is the following:

[image: Plot from code]

In which the top plot is the error and the bottom plot is the impulse response of the low pass filter (red) and the "adapted" algorithm filter (blue).

Its not converging, it should look something like this:

[image: template result]

As you can see the top plot converge into almost 0 error and the bottom plot has no more blue because its behind the red one (since it almost perfectly ajusted its coeficients to the filter)

I would like to know if there are any visible mistakes made by my implementation and perhaps this might be a future reference for people with similar mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was that I wasn't using the correct multiplication for the algorithm, it needs to be a dot product instead of simple the power of 2

so the fix is in the for loop:

```
dotprod = dot(s(i-j,1),s(i-j,1));    
for j=1:(L),
    W(j,1) = W(j,1)+(k*s(i-j,1)/dotprod);
end
```